# Testing Spacy NER model

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I've trained an NER model with the use of Spacy, and I would like to test the accuracy on a test dataset. What would be the best way to perform this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [evaluate command](https://spacy.io/api/cli#evaluate) to evaluate the test set. It would look like this:

```
spacy evaluate ./my-model ./test-data.spacy
```